# How to update a part of the column data using replace function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a table coulmn, the table has thousands of records.

[image]

Currently I am updating the table by running the following query manually for some of the records.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET column = REPLACE(column, 'ABC', 'ABC9')
WHERE where   column like ‘ABC%’
```

Now I am trying to generate a  generic query to update the table by adding a letter '9' after the alphabets.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188395.aspx)** and **[`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188043.aspx)**

**Patindex** - Helps you to identify the *first occurrence* of `numeric` character in the string

**Stuff** - Helps you to insert `9` before the first occurrence of numeric character in the string

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET column = stuff(column,patindex('%[0-9]%',column),0,'9')
```

Comment: You should also explain what it does, But +1 for the solution

Comment: @sagi - Thanks :) updated with MSDN links and some explanation